# Making TodoList in React, how to cross out item when finished (not using index)?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and learning how to make a Todo App. I need to know how to cross out a todo once the checkbox input is clicked, and uncrossed once clicked again (toggle) in a controlled environment. I've put in my research; the thing is, everyone seems to be using index, while I have heard not to use index as it leads towards problems. Any help would be greatly appreciated; here's my code below:

App (parent component)

```
// dependencies
import React from 'react';
// local files
import './App.css';
import List from '../components/List';

class App extends React.Component {
  // state
  state = {
    todos: [
      {key: 0, text: "Go shopping", isCompleted: false},
      {key: 1, text: "Lift", isCompleted: false},
      {key: 2, text: "Go for walk", isCompleted: false}
    ],
    currentTodo: {
      key: "",
      text: "",
      isCompleted: false
    }
  };

  // event handlers


  // JSX
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="title">
          TodoList
        </div>
        <List todos={this.state.todos} />
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default App;
```

List Component:

```
// dependencies
import React from 'react';
// local files

const List = (props) => {
  const TodoList = props.todos.map((todo) => {
    return (
      <div className="TodoItem" key={todo.key}>

          {todo.key} {todo.text}
          <input type="checkbox" />

      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="Show-List">
      {TodoList}
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For update operation you can use `index`, there is no issue

A unique `key` is required for list of items, so that react can React identify which items have changed

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
>   removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
>   the elements a stable identity ( **[Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)** )

---

Hope the below code snippet help you:

```
const TodoList = props.todos.map((todo.index) => {
    return (
      // index is not a good option here, here you should use unique key only
      <div className="TodoItem" key={todo.key}>

          {todo.key} {todo.text}

          // but here you can use the index, so you can update the todo easily
          // as you are just using it to get access of specific todo
          <input type="checkbox" checked={todo.isCompleted} onChange={() => props.handleCheck(index)}/>

      </div>
    );
});
```

**WORKING DEMO :**

[image: Edit lucid-elbakyan-67i3m]

Comment: Hello, I've added the key in my list component, on my div className="TodoItem"> I've added key={todo.key} there. I guess what I'm trying to ask is if there's other ways to toggle the item as completed instead of using index?

Comment: So instead of passing index, you can pass key if its unique, and then search for that todo and update it

Comment: Hi Vivek, I'm still stuck after 30 min.. I get what you're saying, index can be used to get a specific todo. Can you show me how my handleCheck method look like? I'm still learning so I'm not sure how to apply your answer to the handleCheck method

Comment: @LawrenceYoon, okay sure, do one thing, create a working demo of your todo app on codesandbox, so that I can't help you with your existing flow.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-newton-xwlu7?file=/src/app/App.js

Comment: @LawrenceYoon, please check working demo in updated answer.

Comment: Hello, all seems well in the sandbox, but on my code I get TypeError: props.isCompleted is not a function from List.js line 15; I'm not sure where that's coming from

Comment: Please check app/app.js

Comment: I wrote it in myself, and I also tried to paste your answer, still getting the same error :( Still doesn't work for me on VSCode. Works perfectly on sandbox, just when I move everything over I still get the same error

Comment: I'm also not sure where props.isCompleted is coming from, because we didn't pass a method called isCompleted to the onChange event handler on List.js

Comment: @LawrenceYoon, I think you are confused b/w 2 app.js files, please check updated demo again (reload it if its open in browser), hope this will make it clear

Comment: Ohh I see, got it! Mr. Doshi thanks so much for sticking with me! I appreciate your help very much!! Now time to find out myself how you did it! Thank you very much, you're a lifesaver :)

Comment: @LawrenceYoon, no issue, glad to know you got it :).

Comment: I'm not sure I can right now Mr. Doshi, it says I need 15 reputation :( I don't think I can do anything because I'm new, but once I get 15 rep I'll make sure to upvote!

Comment: Gotcha, I accepted the answer and yeah once I get rep I'll make sure to upvote! Thanks once again Mr. Doshi!